# Warning: 1 offset/reduce conflict

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

My target command is like this，for example,save depth=1 exclude=[w1 w2]
But when I compile the file, I have a problem:

```
parser.y: Warning: 1 offset/reduce conflict [-Wconflicts-sr]
parser.y: note: rerun with option '-Wcounterexamples' to generate conflict counterexamples
```

This is part of my bison code:

```
%union {
    char *str;
    int number;
}
%token SAVE DEPTH EXCLUDE
%token LB RB EQ COMMA NUMBER STRING NEWLINE
%%
input:
    | command NEWLINE input
    | command
    ;
strings:
    | STRING
    | strings STRING
    ;
command:
    SAVE DEPTH EQ NUMBER EXCLUDE EQ LB strings RB{ printf("Command parsed successfully.\n"); }
    | error { printf("Error: Invalid command.\n"); }
    ;
%%
int main()
{
    printf("Enter your commands:\n");
    while (1) {
        yyparse();
        if (feof(stdin)) {
            break;
        }
        yylex_destroy();
        yyrestart(stdin);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run `bison -Wcounterexamples parser.y`

```
  Example: • STRING
  Shift derivation
    strings
    ↳ 5: • STRING
  Reduce derivation
    strings
    ↳ 6: strings  STRING
         ↳ 4: ε •
```

The correct EXCLUDE looks like this `EXCLUDE=[w1]` or `EXCLUDE=[x1 m1 a3]`, I want to know why there is such a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example contains another beginners error, which is usually a typo.

You have made the first choice for both the rule `input` and the rule `strings` to be nothing (or epsilon the empty set in computer science terms). Thus the parse cannot tell which rule to use when it finds "nothing"!

This is caused by starting each rule with a choice bar <kbd>|</kbd>.

To be explicit, the rules:

```
input:
    | command NEWLINE input
    | command
    ;
strings:
    | STRING
    | strings STRING
    ;
```

Should be written as:

```
input:
     command NEWLINE input
    | command
    ;
strings:
     STRING
    | strings STRING
    ;
```

(note the deletion of the <kbd>|</kbd>)

If your language was meant to have these features as "optional" you will need to re structure the grammar.